# Where could I get EGL headers on a CentOS machine without X11/Wayland installed with NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: linux, opengl

I found a blog about headless OpenGL from NVIDIA https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/ , but there isn't any egl.h on my machine. I tried downloading egl.h from https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/ , but egl.h depends on eglplatform.h, which depends on X11:

```
#elif defined(__unix__) || defined(USE_X11)

/* X11 (tentative)  */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

typedef Display *EGLNativeDisplayType;
typedef Pixmap   EGLNativePixmapType;
typedef Window   EGLNativeWindowType;

#elif defined(__APPLE__)
```

I heard about mesa, but I doubt its eglplatform.h's compatibility with NVIDIA driver's implementation. How could I use EGL on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by copying the header from the patch https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/attachment?aid=293029&signed_aid=DKkje7OQxO9ql6Tun8a15Q== . Mesa's header should be ok as well because I would not use any window related function at all. All I need to do is just compile my source files.